# white space in un-braced expression

Tags: tcl

An interesting encounter:

```
set v "\{a b\}"
expr $v eq \{a b\}
```

The expression command returns true as expected. But the following also returns true:

```
set v "\{a b\}"
expr $v eq \{a      b\}
```

Basically the number of white spaces between `\{a` and `b\}` are ignored.

I know TCL expression should brace the arguments.

I know nobody would write such code seriously.

I can also guess what is going on:

1. At script level parsing, the white spaces are simply used as word separation, one or more white spaces have same effect.
2. When it comes to command `expr`, it has no access to the "raw" script, all it knows are there are 2 words, `{a` and `b}`, separated by some whitespace
3. So just one white space is used.

But from the point of view TCL as a programming language, is it a bug?

Comment: No, that's exactly as specified. The same thing happens when a string is split up into a list. Every time you want to preserve whitespace, you must quote it.

Comment: Now you're seeing _part_ of why people are told to _always brace your expressions_. There was an experimental move to make code like yours less “surprising” during the 8.0 alphas (in the mid-to-late '90s), but the user community rejected it; having the core language parser have _absolutely no exceptions to its rules at all_ was felt to be a better principle to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third rule of Tcl syntax says

> Words of a command are separated by white space (except for newlines,
>       which are command separators).

(Command names and argument strings are words.)

The first clause in the documentation for `expr` says

> Concatenates args (adding separator spaces between them)

So what happens is that the Tcl parser breaks up the string `expr $v eq \{a      b\}` into five words, discarding the whitespace characters between them. Then the `expr` command concatenates its four arguments into a single string with a single separator space between each pair.

It’s basically the same thing as you see when you perform a list mutation command on a string:

```
% set a {a    b c}
a    b c
% lappend a d
a b c d
```

Documentation:
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)